# DataGridView, How to use if statement for a cell that starts with a string

Tags: c#, datagridview, background-color, cells

I would like to be able to use an if statement to determine the colour of a DGV cell that starts with a string "Manual". I know how to change the cell's colour

```
if (Convert.ToString(DGV_Points.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.StartsWith) == "Manual")
                    {

                    }
```

Also is it possible to disable the restoration of the cell's default colours when a header is clicked?

Comment: The BackColor is in the Style Property: `DGV_Points.Rows[x].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.youNameIt;` To restore it the most efficient way it to store modified Cells in a List<DataGridViewCell> and loop over it when necessary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (DGV_Points.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.ToString().StartsWith("Manual"))
{

}
```

Is this what you were looking for?